# turn off css sheet on specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new to jquery and I'm trying to turn off a specific css sheet when a specific page loads. This is the code that I've been using and I'm not sure that it is correct.

```
if(location.pathname=="/mycart") >= 0){

    $('link[rel=stylesheet][src~="/media/css/responsive.css"]').remove();

}
```

Comment: Just give that style sheet in question an ID. `$('#whatever').remove();`

Comment: That looks correct...did you try it?

Comment: This sounds like something you'd want to do on the server, not on the client side.

Comment: link always uses href not src....

Comment: Looks like mismatching `(` too.

Comment: How do I give a style sheet an ID?

Comment: Unless you are using some sort of fancy template system, why not just actually remove the <link> from the page itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that path name check... also, instead of removing, try disabling the stylesheet:

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf('/mycart') >= 0) {
    $('link[href*="/media/css/responsive.css"]').prop('disable', true);
}
```

Edit: The [`~=` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) looks for a space deliminated word, so use the [`*=` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) instead.

**Update** (full code)

```
<script>
$(function () {
  if (location.pathname.indexOf('/mycart') >= 0) {
    $('link[href*="/media/css/responsive.css"]').prop('disable', true);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, total noob here. Do I put this inside a $(document).ready(function () {   ?

Comment: So it should look like this?  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

if (location.pathname.indexOf('/mycart') >= 0) {
    $('link[href*="/media/css/responsive.css"]').prop('disable', true);

}});
</script>

Comment: BTW, `.prop()` only works in jQuery v1.6+... otherwise use `$('link[href*="/media/css/responsive.css"]')[0].disable = true;`

Comment: For what ever reason that still doesn't work. I found this suggestion on another site and it works. <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

if (location.pathname.indexOf('/mycart') >= 0) {
    jQuery('#responsive').remove();
}});
</script>

Comment: Well remove the script then :P, but first make sure that the selector is targetting the right link... type this into the console: `$('link[href*="/media/css/responsive.css"]').length` it should return `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of complicating things with on the fly style-sheets "canceling" why don't you simply create a wrapper class around objects that change on your page and define two sets of selectors that apply in case the wrapper does or does not have a specific class.

Lets say this is your HTML code.

```
<div class="my_cart">
    <!-- Lots of shiny elements defined inside your cart... -->
</div>
```

Now you simply add two sets of stylesheets depending on how you actually want to style your cart in different situations.

```
.my_cart input {
    ...
}

.my_cart p {
    ...
}
/* The following two selectors will be applied to .my_cart ONLY if it also has the .disabled class assigned to it. */
.my_cart.disabled input {
    ...
}

.my_cart.disabled p {
    ...
}
```

Now all you have to do is following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(location.pathname == "/mycart"){
        $('.my_cart').addClass('.disabled');
    }
});
```

Simple as that.